# Matlab dll included in C# project on client pc

Tags: c#, matlab, dll

I'm working on Matlab and C# projects, I've created a DLL file from the Matlab project and run it on the C# project. 
My code works fine on my computer and on any Windows 7 x64 bit that I've tested.

The problem is with Windows 8, When I'm trying to run my app on Win 8 PC the app collapsed while calling to the main class that included in the DLL.

I tried to catch the error, but no error occurred, the app just crashed.

I've already installed MCR for the specific Matlab version, but it still doesn't work.

I believe that I'm missing some system configuration, can someone help to do some order what exactly should I do in order to run it?

**UPDATE1:**
The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using VisionCameraQA;

using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
namespace VisionCameraQATest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        cls_Main main;
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
             try
        {
            main = new cls_Main();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        }
        }
   }
}
```

The app crashes while getting to `main = new cls_Main();`, it is not reached to the catch at all.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have already please?

Comment: The code actually is not mattered, since the app crashes at the beginning while I'm called to the class from Matlab DLL. I will add the relevant code